# Kendo UI PDF export compatibility issues in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11

I'm presently exporting a Chart and a Grid to a PDF, which works fine in Chrome and Firefox (of course).

In IE11 however, I get:

```
SCRIPT5007: Array.prototype.slice: 'this' is null or undefined
File: kendo.all.min.js, Line: 17, Column: 7305
```

Telerik claims compatibility on IE 10 and up with their PDF export. They also suggest for lower versions of IE (which this isn't) that the proxyUrl parameter be provided in the export.

I've tried it with the proxyUrl, and it still fails in IE.

BUT, this app is running 100% locally and will not have an internet connection anyway, so even if the proxyUrl worked, it wouldn't be a viable solution.

I've yet to test it with Edge, but assumed IE11 would be fine.

Telerik's image export is working fine in IE11 as well.

Edit:
My mitake, it might work after the proxyUrl is provided, but again I cannot use this as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a recent release of Kendo UI which addressed this issue in Internet Explorer, so assuming Telerik/Kendo UI are up to date, this is no longer an issue.